# Как добавить индекс и значения всей строки None к имеющемуся фрейму данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейму данных `df`, нужно добавить последней строкой значения `None`  с индексом "моя строка".

```
for ind in df2.index:
    if ind not in df1.index:
        df1.at[ind] = None
        # df1.loc[(ind),[None]]
```

[Пример данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16_Igi6amH4d5d9auLAYWInWq-M0XpEl4ycRORxLE-6k/edit#gid=0)

| df1 | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index | 1 | 4 |
| First | 2 | 5 |
| Second | 3 | 6 |

| df2 | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index | 1 | 5 |
| First | 2 | 6 |
| Second | 3 | 7 |
| Моя строка | 4 | 8 |

| df1 (после преобразования) | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index | 1 | 4 |
| First | 2 | 5 |
| Second | 3 | 6 |
| Моя строка | None | None |

Comment: @MaxU привела скрин, сейчас еще ссылку на файл добавлю

Comment: Плюс за пример данных текстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]], columns=["Column1", "Column2"], index=["index", "First", "Second"])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
        Column1  Column2
index         1        4
First         2        5
Second        3        6

In [7]: df.loc["Моя строка"] = [np.nan] * df.shape[1]

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
            Column1  Column2
index           1.0      4.0
First           2.0      5.0
Second          3.0      6.0
Моя строка      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: к той же задаче, но немного другой вопрос. После того, как я добавила строки к первому дата фрейму и хочу их сшить, то применяю функцию concat. df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'], sort=False)/. Но выходит ошибка Shape of passed values is (113, 56), indices imply (110, 56).

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

При ваших исходных:

```
df = df.reindex([*df.index, "Моя строка"])
```

df:

```
              1    4
First       2.0  5.0
Second      3.0  6.0
Моя строка  NaN  NaN
```